# Exported function being run in unit tests despite never calling it

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following class:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as Logger from 'js-logger';

import { CookieParser } from './cookie-parser.service';
import { LogLevelConverter } from './loglevel-converter.service';
export class LoggerFactory {
  //Logging levels can be referenced like so: `LoggerFactory.WARN`
  public static readonly DEBUG = Logger.DEBUG;
  public static readonly INFO = Logger.INFO;
  public static readonly WARN = Logger.WARN;
  public static readonly ERROR = Logger.ERROR;
  public static readonly OFF = Logger.OFF;

  private static readonly LOG_LEVEL: string = 'FACTORY_LOG_LEVEL';
  private static initialized = false;

  public static getLogger(name: string): any {
    if (!LoggerFactory.initialized) {
      LoggerFactory.init(name);
    }

    return Logger.get(name);
  }

  private static init(name: string): void {
    //Set default logging level for LoggerFactory
    const DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL = LoggerFactory.ERROR;
    Logger.setLevel(DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL);

    let logLevel: string;

    if (window.document.cookie.indexOf(LoggerFactory.LOG_LEVEL) > -1) {
      logLevel = CookieParser.getCookieValue(LoggerFactory.LOG_LEVEL);
    } else if (LoggerFactory.isLocalStorageSupported()) {
      logLevel = localStorage.getItem(LoggerFactory.LOG_LEVEL);
    }

    if (logLevel) {
      Logger.get(name).setLevel(LogLevelConverter.toLogLevel(logLevel));
    } else {
      Logger.get(name).setLevel(DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL);
    }

    LoggerFactory.initialized = true;
  }

  private static isLocalStorageSupported(): boolean {
    const testKey = 'test',
      storage = window.localStorage;
    try {
      storage.setItem(testKey, '1');
      storage.removeItem(testKey);
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Used for logging the lifecycles of a component
 * Usage: @NgLifecycleLog()
 * @param  {string}         name for the logger
 * @return {ClassDecorator}
 */
export function NgLifecycleLog(name?: string): ClassDecorator {
  return function(constructor: any): void {
    const LIFECYCLE_HOOKS: Array<string> = ['ngOnInit', 'ngOnChanges', 'ngOnDestroy'];

    //If no name is given, default to using the component's constructor's name
    const NAME: string = name ? name : constructor.name;

    const lifecycleLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NAME);

    console.error("SHOULDN'T BE CALLED"); //gets called

    LIFECYCLE_HOOKS.forEach(hook => {
      const original = constructor.prototype[hook];

      constructor.prototype[hook] = function(...args) {
        lifecycleLogger.info(`${hook}`, ...args);
        original.apply(this, args);
      };
    });
  };
}
```

I also have the following unit test:

```
import { LoggerFactory } from './logger-factory.service';

describe('LoggerFactory', () => {
  localStorage.setItem('FACTORY_LOG_LEVEL', 'WARN');
  const LOGGER_NAME = 'unit.testing.name';
  const logger: any = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME);

  it('should provide a logger', () => {
    expect(logger).toBeDefined(logger);
  });

  it('should have the correct name', () => {
    expect(logger.context.name).toEqual(LOGGER_NAME);
  });

  it('should allow for localStorage log level overrides', () => {
    expect(logger.getLevel().name).toEqual('WARN');
  });
});
```

My problem is that even though I'm *never* calling the `NgLifecycleLog()` method, it gets called. This is a problem because I'm trying to use `LoggerFactory` instead of `console` statements in it. When I run the unit test, a call to `NgLifecycleLog()` is made this causes an instance of `LoggerFactory` to be created when I am not expecting it to.

Why is this called? I've tried doing `fdescribe` on the tests to make sure this is the only thing being run and even then, that doesn't fix it.

Comment: It's called because it's called. You created this decorator to decorate something, didn't you? If it's unused, why is it there? Delete it from code base and you will see where it's called.

Comment: Yeah, I use it in a component. I'm not testing the component though. If I'm running the unit test and doing `fdescribe`, the component should never get a chance to use that decorator. Why would it be called if I'm running the unit test and that unit test is **never** calling it?

Comment: I guess you misunderstand how decorators work then. Class decorators are executed once, when decorated class is defined. If decorated class was included to test bundle, decorator function will be called. If this creates problems, then a decorator was designed the wrong way. I'd suggest to update the question to reflect your real code and not just console.error.

Comment: I guess I do. I updated the OP with the real code then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class decorators are executed once, when decorated class is defined. If decorated class was included in test bundle, decorator function will be called.

If decorator function produces side effects or involves other units (this may affect unit tests), it should be refactored.

In this case a decorator patches class prototype methods:

```
const lifecycleLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NAME);

LIFECYCLE_HOOKS.forEach(hook => {
  const original = constructor.prototype[hook];

  constructor.prototype[hook] = function(...args) {
    lifecycleLogger.info(`${hook}`, ...args);
    original.apply(this, args);
  };
});
```

`lifecycleLogger` should be moved from the place where it is called on class decoration to the places where it is actually used:

```
LIFECYCLE_HOOKS.forEach(hook => {
  const original = constructor.prototype[hook];

  constructor.prototype[hook] = function(...args) {
    const lifecycleLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NAME);
    lifecycleLogger.info(`${hook}`, ...args);
    original.apply(this, args);
  };
});
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Also, LoggerFactory.getLogger(NAME) call can be memoized or cached to local variable if needed, but it looks like it's not the case because Logger.get (js-logger lib) already does that.